# Drupal: Password textfield in everypage, how can I remove?

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, drupal-7

After migration, every page add password textfield at the end of every page.

What is this? How can I remove or troubleshoot?

Drupal 7.27 with apache 2.4 and php 7.0 (same problem with php 5.6.35).

[image: Textfield with pass name]
[image: javascript and form]

Answer (score 3):

Look there is a script loaded on these pages (just above the `<form>` itself) that creates the input tags and set the windows focus in it :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var d = document; 
  d.write("<br><br><form method='post'><center><input type='password'...>...");
  // ...
</script>
```

You want to remove this script.

Since there are several ways to include javascript with Drupal it may be difficult to spot the code responsible for that. Given the ugliness of the script itself, it could very well be harcoded in a theme template file (in this case, theme switching during migration would explain why your issue suddenly arose).

The chance is that ugly snippets like this is quite often hardcoded so you can make a search for a part of the js string (e.g. `'d.write("<br><br><form'`) in your project at the root of your site and/or in sites/all.

Lastly, find the guy that wrote this and beat him ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is including a java script in every page which is creating input type password since it is included in every page that's why you are getting this field.
kindly check your requirement for same.

In drupal We can add JS in drupal by following method

1.)By `drupal_add_js()` function

`drupal_add_js()` is drupal api function to include js.

**Example:**

```
drupal_add_js('misc/collapse.js');
```

// add JS file

```
drupal_add_js('misc/collapse.js', 'file');
```

// For including inline javascript

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });', 'inline');
```

//For including inline javascript and includ and includ it in footer

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });', array(
  'type' => 'inline',
  'scope' => 'footer',
  'weight' => 5,
));
```

//For including External JS

```
drupal_add_js('http://example.com/example.js', 'external');
```

//For passing php value to JS

```
drupal_add_js(array(
  'myModule' => array(
    'key' => 'value',
  ),
), 'setting');
```

**Example:**

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/mymodule.js');
```

for more infomation visit https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7.x

2.)Adding by Form API

we can used '#attached' property of form api for including js

**Example:**

```
$form['#attached']['js'] = array(
  drupal_get_path('module', 'ajax_example') . '/ajax_example.js',
);
```

3.)Adding JS in info file

We can including javascript in script file

**Example:**

```
name = My theme
description = Theme developed by me.
core = 7.x
engine = phptemplate

scripts[] = mytheme.js
```

4.)By preprocess function

if we want to conditionaly include JS we can include it in preprocess function

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (true) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/mytheme.js');
    $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js(); // necessary in D7?
  }
}
```